# Why is callback function into directive controller not being recognized?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get a directive to work with its own controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/xfbgjun5/14/

However, when I click the button:

```
var template = '<button ng-click="vm.addItem()">add item</button>'+
               '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in vm.items">{{item}}</li></ul>';
```

It tells me that:

```
Error: vm.add is not a function
```

even though I define `controllerAs` and `bindToController`:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        datasource: '=',
        add: '&'
    },
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    template: template        
};
```

and pass in a scope method from the main controller:

```
<div item-menu datasource="customers" add="addCustomer()"></div>
```

**Why does it not recognize `add` as a function on `vm`?**

---

**ADDENDUM: The controller looks like this:**

```
.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = ['First','Second','Third'];
    $scope.score = 0;
    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
        $scope.score++;
    }
})
```

Comment: can you show your controller?

Comment: ok, I added it above

Comment: where is `add` defined? i only see `addCustomer`.

Comment: in the directive scope `add: '&'`, it worked in another example without a controller in the directive, here: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/xfbgjun5/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind to attributes, you have to bind it to `$scope`, not the controller.

```
var controller = function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    function init() {
        vm.items = angular.copy($scope.datasource);
    }
    init();

    vm.addItem = function() {
        $scope.add();
        vm.items.push('new one');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xfbgjun5/15/

Comment: Thanks for finding that, I had based this code on this article which uses both `vm.datasource` and `vm.add()` suggesting that these will work bound to the controller: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer to your question in this [blog post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html)

If you use Angular 1.3 you need to add to the directive the following line of code:

```
bindToController: true,
```

Check the blog post and the code snippets.